# Semi-Automatic Classification QGIS Plug-In Error When Running Maximum Likelihood Classifier

Tags: qgis-3, scp

I have the following python error when trying to run the Maximum Likelihood classification in Semi-Automatic Classification plugin version 8.2.2 on QGIS 3.28.5. Python version is 3.9.5

File "C:\Users/SeanSuzEdieLois/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\interface\classification_tab.py", line 143, in run_classification_action
run_classifier()
File "C:\Users/SeanSuzEdieLois/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\interface\classification_tab.py", line 487, in run_classifier
if output is None:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'output' referenced before assignment